# Journey Builder Custom Activity: How to secure the UI endpoint url?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, single-sign-on, security-token, custom-activity

I created another [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194308/journey-builder-custom-activity-how-to-load-data-extensions-in-ui) to ask how to load data extension in Custom Activity UI. Now another question: how can I secure the endpoint page, so I know it is from that Marketing Cloud Journey Builder Business Unit instance?

for example, if my UI endpoint is https://www.mysite.com/endpoint/, I can see it is embedded as iframe in Journey Builder, but there is no parameter passed to endpoint, how can I secure it so it only loads if it is used for that Marketing Cloud instance? Is there any SSO or access token passed to Endpoint applicaiton? This is only for Custom Activity UI, NOT the data workflow after journey is activated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can secure access by using `"useJwt": true` in each of your activity arguments [as documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/encode-custom-activities-using-jwt-app-signature.htm) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/encode-custom-activities-using-jwt.htm):

> When your application is called, Marketing Cloud posts the encoded JWT to the activity's endpoint. The JWT lets your application know that the user calling the API is from Marketing Cloud.

However, it appears you wan to restrict access to the index.html file. In that case, the only way that I can think of is to build in IP address restriction, so that you will only accept requests from Marketing Cloud. The complete list of IP addresses used by Marketing Cloud is [listed here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/exacttarget_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists/), you don't need all of these. I can't recall which ones that Journey Builder uses, but it would be very easy for you to check.

Comment: thank you @Eliot, will test the activity and mark the answer accepted later :)

Comment: I looked into this, given the request for Index/config.json comes from the browser, not mc servers, it doesnt seem possible to validate against the IP of Marketing Cloud. @Bo Hu, did this end up working for you somehow?

Comment: @Doug You are right, httpreferrer uses user browser IP address than the SFMC server IP. so IP restriction check is not possible. The only 'restriction' I think may work: on index.html, check if window.top contains MC url pattern, if not matching, hide the content etc.